# How to obtain a lineal or polynomial regression?

Tags: r, regression

I'm doing an interferometric research and the data I have is in different columns in a csv document file.
I have around 10 columns of displacement data by date corresponding to different points. So, my question is how can I obtain a lineal regression or polynomial one in R, having in mind that I have 11 columns - 1st one is Date and then I have 10 columns called Point1, Point2...etc., where I have my displacement numbers. I don't know if I need to add more columns for the coordinates?? Any idea would be useful, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not apply any type of linear regression to time series data.

**You have been warned.**

Creating the linear model:

```
lm(dependent ~ .-Time, data = data)
```

will yield the linear model. Here `.` means all columns except dependent.

```
lm(dependent ~ Col1 + I(Col1^2) + Col2 + I(Col2^2) + I(Col1 * Col2) + I(Col1^2 * Col2^2)..., data = data)
```

will yield you the polynomial regression. Here you can fill the "..." with more terms but interaction and power terms should be in `I()`

You can also use `poly()` function instead of writing all the powers of a term.

```
lm(dependent ~ poly(Col1, degree = 2) + poly(Col2, degree = 2) + poly(Col1 * Col2, degree = 2), data = data)
```

More easily you can get the whole 2nd degree model by just:

```
lm(dependent ~ poly(Col1, Col2, degree = 2), data = data)
```

This would yield `Col1 + Col1^2 + Col2 + Col2^2 + Col1*Col2`

Comment: I think `poly(Col1, Col2, degree = 2)` will work to get the full model?